# Laravel route api without api key and csrf token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I have

```
Route::filter('pre_api', function($route, $request)
{
}
```

to do the api key validation and its working fine.
Is it possible to make a plain request to route api which allow client access to  api without api key?

Comment: install package cors and change config file cors.php

Comment: You have to write the custom route for client access. You can specify multiple filters in routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write api requests in routes/api.php.

You need to install the cors package in laravel.

toutrial for install core -> https://medium.com/@KrishaWeb/cross-origin-request-blocked-error-in-laravel-5-5-a733232795e4

example :

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() {

    Route::get('/hello',function(){
    return 'hello';
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the middleware because my laravel version is 4.2.